# What is the difference between x^2 and I(x^2) in R?

Tags: r, sas, glm

What is the difference between these two models in R?

```
model1 <- glm(y~ x + x^2, family=binomial(link=logit), weights=numbers))
model2 <- glm(y~ x + I(x^2),family=binomial(link=logit), weights=numbers))
```

Also what is the equvalent of `I(x^2)` in SAS?

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. Please read `?formula` and if you remain unclear about the difference then edit your question to make clear what would be the remaining questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `I()` function means **'as is'** whereas the `^n` (to the power of n) operator means **'include these variables and all interactions up to n way'**

This means:

`I(X^2)` is literally regressing Y against X squared and

`X^2` means include X and the 2 way interaction of X but since it is only one variable there is no interaction so it returns only itself i.e. X. Note that in your formula you say `X + X^2` which translates to `X + X` which in the formula syntax is only taken into account once. I.e. one of the two Xs will be removed.

Demonstration:

```
Y <- runif(100)
X2 <- runif(100)
df <- data.frame(Y,X1,X2)

b <- lm( Y ~ X2 + X2^2 + X2,data=df)

> b

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X2 + X2^2 + X2, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           X2  
    0.48470      0.05098  


a <- lm( Y ~ X2 + I(X2^2),data=df)

> a

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X2 + I(X2^2), data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           X2      I(X2^2)  
    0.47545      0.11339     -0.06682
```

Hope it helps!